# How to solve errors from running jobs in parallel using Jenkins and watir webdriver?

Tags: ruby, jenkins, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running tests from Jenkins on Windows and tests which work fine when only one is executing at a time encounter errors when multiple jobs are running on separate build threads at the same time. I am using Watir webdriver. The creation of the browser is using the code:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :profile => profile, :http_client=>client
```

The tests are written in Ruby with Cucumber and I am using tags to run a subset of the tests in each job. The tests are executed with cucumber from the "Execute Windows Batch Command". Opening up two command line instances on my desktop and running the jobs in parallel works fine.

A couple of different errors seem to recurr. One is:

```
[0412/111507:ERROR:ipc_sync_channel.cc(378)] Canceling pending sends
[0412/111552:ERROR:proxy_launcher.cc(114)] WaitForInitialLoads failed.
[0412/111552:ERROR:proxy_launcher.cc(556)] Failed to ConnectToRunningBrowser
[0412/111552:ERROR:automation_proxy.cc(319)] Channel error in AutomationProxy.
[0412/111552:ERROR:ipc_sync_channel.cc(378)] Canceling pending sends
[0412/111552:ERROR:ipc_sync_channel.cc(378)] Canceling pending sends
Unable to either launch or connect to Chrome. Please check that ChromeDriver is up-to-date. Using Chrome binary at: C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

the other is

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

An example run which works via command line on my desktop and not through Jenkins is:

```
cucumber --tags @event_discounts ENVIRONMENT=beta
```

and

```
cucumber --tags @WhiteList ENVIRONMENT=BETA
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: How are you running the tests in parallel (code example)? Does it work fine with other browsers, for example Firefox?

Comment: Ahah, found the solution while testing your suggestions. I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to open services, open the properties for Jenkins, click on the "Log On" tab and check "Allow service to interact with desktop" then I restarted Jenkins by going to `http://localhost:8080/safeRestart`
and clicking yes, now tests will run in parallel correctly.

Unfortunately I now get pop-ups about Interactive Services Detection, but I can move that to the corner of the screen and ignore it.